# Как заполнить столбец в MySql таблице значениями из Excel

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

Есть табличка в экселе. Из нее нужно подсадить в таблицу SQL значения из нескольких столбцов экселя. Сервер - MySql.

Comment: Какую бд вы используете?

Comment: Mysql. Создала таблицу в Workbench

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сохранить данные из Excel как CSV, а в MySQL дать команду [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

Посмотрите этот [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310166/how-to-import-an-excel-file-in-to-a-mysql-database) на Главном SO